# Paypal payment split in 2 partners

Tags: php, paypal

Is it possible that a user pay with paypal (for example) 50 €, and "behind" diversify those 50 € 2 partners, 3, N? (25 and 25) or (20, 20 and 10) (N, N, N)

The diversify parts go to other paypal accounts or other places

Without the user suffers split payments, and without accounting to month, in an automated way.

Thanks

Comment: you will have better chance of getting an answer if you ask this question in paypal support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Parallel or Chained Payments

- **Parallel Payments** The buyer pays a fee that automatically splits to the receivers. The buyer knows exactly where the money goes. **Example**: The buyer pays 60$ from which 20$ go to ReceiverA, 30$ goes to ReceiverB and 10$ go to ReceiverC. The buyer can see the amounts and the receivers
- **Chained Payments** The buyer pays you (the API Caller) the whole amount, you (again, the API Caller) decide whether to keep some money or not and then split the rest to the receivers. The receivers and the amount of money they get is hidden from the buyer. Chained payments can be delayed.

More information [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and documentation.
I will review and study these ways to do

Answer (score 1):

You have to know about paypal adaptive payments. you can find it here.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/